# MySQL Service startup error

Tags: mysql, windows, server-variables

When I am starting mysql service it shuts down after 5 seconds.
The error description is:

```
Faulting application mysqld.exe, version 0.0.0.0, faulting module mysqld.exe, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x002b8853.
```

In Warning log is given:

```
option 'net_buffer_length': unsigned value 8388608 adjusted to 1048576.
```

I need to run mysql from service and standalone application is not a solution for me. 
What may be the root cause of this issue and how to fix this problem? Is it caused due to some new windows patches installation?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked your error log file? I am waiting for your feedback

Comment: Still did not get any solution. Most probably my windows permissions changed and MySql is running as standalone application byt not running from services. Still searching for the solution

Comment: Have you checked your error log file? Update the latest errors from error log file.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of **net_buffer_length** variable in mysql configuration file and set it to **1048576** and then try to start your service. It should work.

Comment: During startup E:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.30-community-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) this log gets printed but in this case this did not come

Comment: Check your Error log file and provide me the what actual error you got